# "malformed array literal" error in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I got an error in `PL/pgSQL`:

> "ERROR:  malformed array literal: "2019-11-22 09:18:07.248537" DETAIL:
>   Array value must start with "{" or dimension information. CONTEXT: 
>   PL/pgSQL function chargelengtth() line 11 at FOR over SELECT rows"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chargelengtth() RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE chargetime integer;
DECLARE othertime integer;
DECLARE total integer;
DECLARE charge_length text[];
DECLARE chargestatus text;
DECLARE otherstatus text;
BEGIN
    total := 0;
    chargetime := 0;
FOR charge_length IN
    SELECT * FROM table_name
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Stuff: %', charge_length;
    IF(charge_length[diagnostic] = 'Charging' AND chargetime = 0) THEN
        chargetime := extract(epoch from charge_length[time]);
    END IF;

    IF(charge_length[diagnostic] != 'Charging') THEN
        othertime := extract(epoch from charge_length[time]);
        total := total + (othertime - chargetime);
        chargetime := 0;
    END IF;

END LOOP;
RETURN to_char(total * interval '1 sec','HH24h MIm');
END$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
SELECT * FROM chargelengtth()`
```

can you please share your knowledge to resolve this issue.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you only need to write `declare` **once**

Comment: Why are you using such an inefficient loop to begin with? You can do this with a single query, no need for looping

Comment: how to do this in single query, could you please give me sample ?

Comment: see my answer - it's not totally clear to me what you are doing though. If you had provided some sample data and expected results this would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) you need to use a record variable when you want to loop over a SELECT statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chargelengtth() 
  RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE 
  chargetime integer;
  othertime integer;
  total integer;
  chargestatus text;
  otherstatus text;
  l_row record; --<< here
BEGIN
  total := 0;
  chargetime := 0;
  FOR l_row IN SELECT * FROM table_name
  LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Stuff: %', l_row;
      IF (l_row.diagnostic = 'Charging' AND chargetime = 0) THEN
          chargetime := extract(epoch from l_row.time);
      END IF;

      IF (l_row.diagnostic != 'Charging') THEN
          othertime := extract(epoch from l_row.time);
          total := total + (othertime - chargetime);
          chargetime := 0;
      END IF;

  END LOOP;
  RETURN to_char(total * interval '1 sec','HH24h MIm');
END$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT chargelengtth()
```

---

As far as I can tell, you can replace this with a single SELECT statement. Assuming the `time` column is a `timestamp`, I *think* the following is equivalent to what you are doing (except for the formatting of the `interval` at the end):

```
with ct (chargetime) as (
  select time 
  from table_name
  where diagnostic = 'Charging'
  limit 1
)
select sum(t.time - ct.chargetime) 
from the_table t
  cross join ct
where t.diagnostic <> 'Charging'
```

The retrieval of the `chargetime` is a bit confusing as you seem to rely on some order of the rows, yet your query has no `order by`. The `limit 1` without an `order by` does essentially the same, but if you want reproducible results you should really specify an `order by` (also for your FOR loop statement)

Comment: `DATETIME, C 
    DATETIME, CPE 
    DATETIME, C 
    DATETIME, C 
    DATETIME, C 
    DATETIME, CPE 
    DATETIME, PDE`
for above result i need to calculate the time diff of first & second(C & CPE) record as C,   second & third record as CPE(CPE & C), third & fourth record as C 
and find the overall C and CPE  total of time differneces.